# Silverlight onLoad event not fired inside Google Wave

Tags: silverlight, google-wave

I am creating a wave gadget base on Silverlight 3. It all works great. Problem is that I want to add some functionality when SL control get loaded. So In "Object" definition of SL, I have added a param for "onLoad" and added a dummy JS function in the gadget to have a simple alert.  But I am not seeing that alert when gadget gets loaded. After debugging I saw that "onLoad" event for silverlight control never fired. When I test the same SL control in a stand alone test page, "onLoad" does get fired appropriately.
I think it has something to do with how Google Wave client hosts the SL control. Any information or help will be greatly appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>I also tried to use silverwave and have the same problems.
The XAP loads and the Constructor seems to be executed, but the control stays empty.</del>

Have you found an answer?

After many hours I found an answer, at least for my question.

1. All URLs must be HTTPS    (I forgot the Silverlight.js)
2. You need a clientaccesspolicy.xml in your Webroot. [Found here](http://community.dynamics.com/blogs/cesardalatorre/comments/9579.aspx)

Now it works perfectly.